# CRM manager - Dropdown list saving chosen option

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate

I have two databases:
-patients
-workers

Both connected in OneToMany relationship. Patients are shown in form of a list where each patient has a 'Worker' row (dropdown list) which should assign chosen worker to a given patient. I have no idea how to save chosen option from dropdown (without any additional button - preferred).

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <form:select path="workers">
        <form:option value="Not Assigned" />
            <c:forEach var="worker" items="${workers}">
            <form:option value="${worker}">${worker.firstName} ${worker.lastName}
        </form:option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Actual result - both aren't linked together, refreshing database discard changes.